# Convert JavaScript file into dll file

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, webforms, bundle

I have a project with Visual Studio 2012 and i have Java Script files, and CSS files in this project.
I want to make all JavaScript files as DLLs and CSS files as DLLs just like my C# Code.
Is that could be done ?, And with what tool ?
And if I'm working with bundles it will still can read from it?
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for **JavaScript but not css** using VisualStudio. You need to add your js files as Embedded resource and then reference them in your code.

this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398930(v=vs.100).aspx) goes into details but basically

1. You add the file as an embedded resource thought VS
2. Use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` to register it
3. Add a web resource attribute `[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("SampleControl.UpdatePanelAnimation.js", "application/x-javascript")]`

**Personally I wouldn't recommend it**. It makes the JavaScript horrible to debug, it prevents client side caching and it forces you to rebuild your site if you need to change the javaScript. I'd simply add a `<script>` tag, like everyone's always done.

[MSDN article on style sheet resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309314.aspx) but basically it just references it using a link tag, so it's not the same as above.

Comment: Thank you for help @Liam, you mean that it will be slow and working from my server not from client side as usual ? 
Also does it works for Bundle ?

Comment: The code is always **executed** on the client and **loaded** from  the server. Which ever way you embed it, resource or script tag, the above is always true. So it has no practical advantage in the running of the javascript.

Comment: I need it for more secure and Enhancement...
Beside that I want to know if i can use converted JavaScript file with bundle or not?

Comment: **JavaScript is never secure**. ASP.Net cannot execute JavaScript. The browser always executes the javaScript and there is no way to prevent the user having access to this code as it has to be in plain text. If you want to perform secure operations you should do this server side, not client side but this is all a whole other topic. Bundling depends on how your bundling the script.

Comment: Thank you @Liam, I know that JavaScript isn't secure and it depends on browser but i just want the most secure setting for every single file in my project... It seems that bundling will be enough ... If you have more advanced suggestion i will be glad to hear about.